# Rate Limit Apache 2 Access Control?

Tags: apache2, access-control-list

I'm not doing anything fancy.  I'm just using Apache2 access control to password protect a directory.

I thought it would be smart if Apache would limit how frequently users can attempt to authenticate username and password from a given IP.  It would be a cheap way to thwart brute force password attempts without DoSing legitimate user login attempts.

I searched and couldn't find anything specific to this and I was surprised. Is there a way to do it?  Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://johnleach.co.uk/words/2012/05/15/rate-limiting-with-apache-and-mod-security/) indicates you can do it with [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) using something like the following:

```
SecRuleEngine On

<LocationMatch "^/somepath">
  SecAction initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},pass,nolog
  SecAction "phase:5,deprecatevar:ip.somepathcounter=1/1,pass,nolog"
  SecRule IP:SOMEPATHCOUNTER "@gt 60" "phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:509,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1,nolog"
  SecAction "phase:2,pass,setvar:ip.somepathcounter=+1,nolog"
  Header always set Retry-After "10" env=RATELIMITED
</LocationMatch>

ErrorDocument 509 "Rate Limit Exceeded"
```

More discussion on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second).